# Retry logic for Azure EventHub PartitionedSender

Tags: c#, azure, azure-eventhub, retry-logic

I am sending / recieving data from an Azure Event Hub. As I have a requirement  messages must be processed in sequence by the consumer, I have decided to go with a PartitionSender and always send events to the same partition.

Under "Consistency" in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-availability-and-consistency it says about the PartitionSender:

*With this type of configuration, you must keep in mind that if the particular partition to which you are sending is unavailable, you will receive an error response. As a point of comparison, if you do not have an affinity to a single partition, the Event Hubs service sends your event to the next available partition.*

So if there is an error I want to implement retry logic that tries to send using another partition. (I have 4)

I don't know how to trigger this error, so I am a little unsure where in the code I have to implement the Retry logic.

My guess is that is the "Sender.SendAsync(data)" that will throw and it is here I should implement the retry logic

This is the relevant code:

```
    private EventHubSender _sender;

     private EventHubSender Sender(int partitionId)
    {
        if (_sender == null)
        {
            _sender = CreatePartitionedSender(partitionId);
        }
        return _sender;
    }

    private static EventHubSender CreatePartitionedSender(int partitionId)
    {
        var eventHubClient = EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString(SnakeHubSendSas);
        return eventHubClient.CreatePartitionedSender(partitionId.ToString());
    }

    public void SendToEventHub(string json, long sequenceNumber)
    {            
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Sending message: sequence number '" + sequenceNumber + "'");

        var data = new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));
        data.Properties.Add("SequenceNumber", sequenceNumber);

        try
            {
                Sender(1).SendAsync(data);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }         
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I known, you could leverage the `PartitionSender` object to send events to a specific partition regarding consistency for your application. Also, you could capture the exception when the particular partition you are sending is unavailable, then send your events to another specific partition. But at this point, your secondary partition could be unavailable at some time and you need to add additional logic to handle events from that partition.

Per my understanding, you could leverage [EventHubClient.Send](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventhubclient#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_EventHubClient_Send_Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_EventData_) method to send your events, in order to automatically distribute your events between partitions of your Event Hub for the greatest amount of up time, and stamp your events with a custom sequence state property to ensure ordering and keep the state of your events by your processing application.

Comment: I am sort of leaning towards handle the exception and then send it to another partition. It is ugly, but it looks like it is the easiest to do.

Comment: I have tried to leverage [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) to decompile Microsoft.ServiceBus, but found nothing about the Exception that indicates the particular partition is unavailable. But I found that messaging exceptions inherit from MessagingException. So I assumed that you could capture the [MessagingException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.messagingexception) for a workaround to implement your retry logic.